# missing text in tabPanel output

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that has two outputs:

- `plot` is a simple graph and
- `session` has a text string of some session info.

I'm showing the plot in a tab and would like to show the session text below the plot. If I use this:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(title = "OC Curve", 
                       plotOutput("plot"), 
                       p("is anyone there?"))))
```

the text "is anyone there?" is exactly where I would expect it (along with the plot). However,

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(title = "OC Curve", 
                       plotOutput("plot"), 
                       p(textOutput("session")))))
```

doesn't show the plot or text. I can verify that `session` exists:

```
mainPanel(
  p(textOutput("session")),
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(title = "OC Curve", 
                       plotOutput("plot"), 
                       p("is anyone there?"))))
```

Here, the `session` text sits nicely above the tab.

I'm using shiny_0.8.0 with R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit).

Thanks,

Max

Comment: Try using the code you have in your second block, (i.e. the code you want) but don't wrap the `textOutput` in `p()` - does that work?

Comment: I have an application that is essentially identical to what you want with the same code - are you getting any error messages? Is the page greying out or just not displaying anything? Could there be an extra comma somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't show the plot or text because you don't provide a text or a plot to show it. Add this to your server for example:

```
server <- function(input,output){
  output$session= renderText({
    "some text here "
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(0)})
}
```

Comment: The plot will render fine when the extra text output is not there. Your code had the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can't use the same `textOutput` more than once (apparently). My code has `p(textOutput("session"))` in another output. Removing that and using:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(title = "OC Curve", 
                       plotOutput("plot"), 
                       p(textOutput("session")))))
```

works. I'll have to clone the `session` object to use it in more than one place.

Thanks,

Max